# Angular - ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I have an Angular7 frontend and Laravel backend. I tested the endpoints on POSTMAN and it works very well. However when I tested on the Serve, it loaded nothing, and I got this error.

I did log.console and I got this error:

> ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be5RO.png)

[postmanscrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Fob.png)

**ApiController:**

```
public function indexSmsmt()
{
    $smsmts = Smsmt::all();
    return response()->json(['success' => true,'data'=>$smsmts], $this->successStatus);
}

public function showSmsmt($id)
{
    $smsmt = Smsmt::find($id);
    if (is_null($smsmt)) {
        return $this->sendError('SMS Incoming not found.');
    }

    return response()->json(['success' => true,'data'=>$smsmt], $this->successStatus);
}

public function storeSmsmt(Request $request)
{
    $smsmt = Smsmt::create($request->all());
    return response()->json(['success' => $smsmt], $this-> successStatus);
}

public function editSmsmt($id)
{
    $smsmt = Smsmt::find($id);
    return response()->json(['success' => true,'data'=>$smsmt], $this->successStatus);
}

public function updateSmsmt(Request $request, $id)
{
    $smsmt = Smsmt::find($id);
    $smsmt = $smsmt->update($request->all());
    return response()->json(['success' => true,'data'=>$smsmt], $this->successStatus);
}

public function deleteSmsmt($id)
{
    $smsmt = Smsmt::find($id)->delete();
    return response()->json(['success' => true], $this->successStatus);
}
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    apiUrl:   'http://exampl.com/api',
};
```

**smsmt.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Smsmt } from '../models/smsmt';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.prod';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SmsmtService {
    private API_URL= environment.apiUrl;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getSmsmts (): Observable<Smsmt[]> {

        return this.http.get<Smsmt[]>(this.API_URL + '/indexSmsmt')
        .pipe(
            tap(smsmts => console.log('Fetch smsmts')),
            catchError(this.handleError('getSmsmts', []))
        );
    }

    getSmsmt(id: number): Observable<Smsmt> {

        const url = this.API_URL + '/editSmsmt' + '/{id}';

        return this.http.get<Smsmt>(url).pipe(
            tap(_ => console.log(`fetched smsmt id=${id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<Smsmt>(`getSmsmt id=${id}`))
        );
    }

    addSmsmt (smsmt): Observable<Smsmt> {
        return this.http.post<Smsmt>(this.API_URL + '/storeSmsmt', smsmt, 
            httpOptions).pipe(
                tap((smsmt: Smsmt) => console.log(`added smsmt w/ id=${smsmt.id}`)),
                catchError(this.handleError<Smsmt>('addSmsmt'))
            );
    }

    updateSmsmt (id, smsmt): Observable<any> {
        const url = this.API_URL + '/updateCSmsmt' + '/{id}';
        return this.http.put(url, smsmt, httpOptions).pipe(
            tap(_ => console.log(`updated smsmt id=${id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateSmsmt'))
        );
    }

    deleteSmsmt (id): Observable<Smsmt> {
        const url = this.API_URL + '/deleteSmsmt' + '/{id}';

        return this.http.delete<Smsmt>(url, httpOptions).pipe(
            tap(_ => console.log(`deleted smsmt id=${id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<Smsmt>('deleteSmsmt'))
        );
     }

    private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
        return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

            // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
            console.error(error); // log to console instead

            // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
            return of(result as T);
        };
    }
}
```

**smsmt.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SmsmtService } from '../../../services/smsmt.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Smsmt } from '../../../models/smsmt';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-bulk-sms-outbox',
    templateUrl: './bulk-sms-outbox.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./bulk-sms-outbox.component.scss']
})

export class BulkSmsOutboxComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['msisdn', 'message', 'telco','error_message','error_code', 'package_id'];
    data: Smsmt[] = [];
    isLoadingResults = true;    
    constructor(private api: SmsmtService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.api.getSmsmts()
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.data = res;
                console.log(this.data);
                this.isLoadingResults = false;
            }, err => {
                console.log(err);
                this.isLoadingResults = false;
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        document.body.className = '';
    } 
}
```

**component.html**

```
<tr  *ngFor="let datas of data| paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
    <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{datas.msisdn}}</td>
    <td>{{datas.short_code_called}}</td>
    <td>{{datas.package_id}}</td>
    <td>{{datas.error_message}}</td>
    <td>{{datas.error_code}}</td>
</tr>
```

Nothing is being loaded.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: explain in detail what you really need and what is the actual result

Comment: I want to display the data in component.html. But nothing is coming out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When fetching the data in Laravel, you're doing

```
return response()->json(['success' => true,'data'=>$smsmts], $this->successStatus);
```

And returns an object with an Array INSIDE of that object
Somethig like:

```
{
   "sucess":"bla bla bla";
   "data":[ ... ] <- Here
}
```

The data you want to display is in that variable `data`

In the file **smsmt.service.ts**, the method 'getSmsmts()' receives an Array of `Smsmts[]` ( `this.http.get<Smsmt[]>`), but it's NOT what you are sending from the backend.

The backend sends an OBJECT (with an Array inside) but the http.get() is waiting for an ARRAY. That's why it throws the error.

You should receive the http.get() method receive an object, like this:

```
getSmsmts (): Observable<any> { // Change here to any
    return this.http.get<any>(this.API_URL + '/indexSmsmt') // and here too
    .pipe(
        tap(smsmts => console.log('Fetch smsmts')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getSmsmts', []))
    );
}
```

Now, in the **smsmts.component.ts** file, try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getSmsmts()
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.data = res.data; // change 'res' to 'res.data'
            console.log(this.data);
            this.isLoadingResults = false;
        }, err => {
            console.log(err);
            this.isLoadingResults = false;
        });
}
```

This may work. Not used to work with .pipe and .taps, but it should work.
Note that this is a workaround, it's not recomended to receive and return `any`. You could make an interface like "RequestResponse" with two atributes : *sucess* and *data* and that way, you avoid using the `any` type

Comment: When I changed 'res' to 'res.data', it underline it as red and I got another error:  any
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Smsmt[]'.ts(2339)

Comment: Try to change the '.subscribe(res => { .... })' to .subscribe((res: any) => { ... })'.   This will remove the underline, and probably solve the issue

Comment: Change the return type of the service 'getSmsmts()' to Observable<any> aswell. The thing is, the method returns an Array, but the backend sends a response, with the array inside of it. That's why the errors

Comment: I am very sorry. Please am a bit bit confused. Can you help me update your answer in the code

Comment: Yes , I can, but wait a bit, because im on my phone xD let me reach my office and i'll explain :)

Comment: @Mofolumike In your question, post a print-screen of the response from `return response()->json(['success' => true,'data'=>$smsmts], $this->successStatus);`.
On postman or something like that.
I need to check that response to help

Comment: I have updated it with the screenshots of the error and postman response

Comment: @Mofolumike Done, edited :)
Hope you understand what I changed and why
Tell me if worked

Comment: If there is any other better way of doing it apart from .pipe and .taps, you can suggest. Am new to Angular

Comment: @Mofolumike The pipe makes you able to show data without manipulation...simply remove the .pipe and .tap, leave only `return this.http.get<any>(this.API_URL + '/indexSmsmt');`
Now, you can make errorHandler on `.catch()`, but i dont use that, My error handler is on the server, so, I don't really use error handler on front end

Did my answer worked?

Comment: I have really learnt a lot from you. Please am very sorry for this. Can you show me how you really do yours because the code have really give me a lot of headache

Comment: @Mofolumike I dont work with Laravel, but the output is the same.
In my service, I got something like:
`GetDadosAcomp(dataInicia?l: string, dataFinal?: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.base + '/api/acomp', { params: params });
  }
`

And in the component

`this.acompService.GetDadosAcomp().subscribe((res: any) => {
   this.acomp = res.message;
  });`

This 'acomp' is an simple array
This might not be a good way to do it, so you should always read docs and check youtube or something